# Javascript: "this" in nested objects

Tags: javascript, this

I am working on a program that has an object called "player" which is created from the constructor "snake".

```
var player = {
  x: 0,

  sayX: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }
}
```

That code works fine. However, I want to access the "sayX" function from another object called "ani".

```
var ani = {
  x: 10,

  sayAll: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
    player.sayX();
  }
}
```

When I try to run ani.sayAll, sayX logs undefined because it uses a "this", but I could not specify which "this" it was referencing.

Is there any way around this.

EDIT:
Actually, that entire code is inside another object. Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: [Works fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/qbmq2td2/) you must be doing something else.

Comment: When you call `player.sayX();`, `this` will refer to `player`. Have a look at the [MDN documentation about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: player.sayX() works correctly, but when I run it inside of ani, it logs undefined.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine.  See fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/rb3k6udq/

Comment: *"but when I run it inside of ani, it logs undefined."* It can't. `player.sayX();` will always produce the same outcome, no matter where it is called (assuming you didn't change `player.x`).

Comment: @Polygon Can you write up an example that produces the incorrect output? Both myself and RJM have shown that the code you've given us works as expected.

Comment: ^ See also [mcve].

Comment: *"Actually, that entire code is inside another object. Would that have something to do with it?"* Most likely not. What `this` refers to primarily depends on how a function is *called*. Given `player.sayX();`, `this` inside `sayX` will refer to `player`. Again, where `player.sayX();` occurs doesn't change that.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post a complete example (see the link above) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Plygon/pen/JXzRyX?editors=1011
This is the link for the code that I am trying to run. It is pretty complex (for me at least), but I got rid of everything that doesn't effect what happens.

Basically, if you press "Every Second", it runs player.move() every second, but if you press "once", it runs it at the next second.

It first logs this.x inside of the player class, then logs player.x.

Answer (score 1):

> sayX **returns** undefined

The function is running properly, but you don't return anything in `sayAll`, hence why it is *return*ing `undefined`.

```js
var player = {
  x: 0,
  sayX: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
    return 'anything';
  }
};

var ani = {
  x: 10,
  sayAll: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
    return player.sayX();
  }
};

ani.sayAll(); // logs '10', then '0', and returns 'anything';
```

*Sample Screenshot*:

[image: Code when run in Chrome dev tools]

Comment: @Polygon, I don't get that result when I run the code in Chrome devtools (see added screenshot). What browser / environment are you using where you get a different result?

Answer (score -1):

Make the 'sayX' function like this:

```
sayX: function() {
    console.log(player.x);
}
```

and make the 'sayAll' function like this:

```
sayAll: function() {
    console.log(ani.x);
    player.sayX();
}
```

this should works.

Comment: While this may work, there is nothing wrong with the code the OP has, so why change it? This is more of a workaround than a proper solution for the issue.

Comment: That does work. However, I want to have the possibility of creating multiple "player" objects, and that only works if there is only one.

Comment: I think that when I use 'this' keyword inside a function I am refer to the function and not to the parent of function.

Comment: No, `this` does not refer to the function, unless **explicitly** set so, which is *very* uncommon. I recommend to read the MDN documentation to learn more about how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this